# static assert for C90 on gcc

Tags: c, gcc, static-assert

[`static_assert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) is a pretty great capability available since C11.

For pre-C11 compilers though, this capability must be emulated.
It's not too hard, there are many examples available over Internet.

For example :

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(CONDITION, MSG) \
typedef char static_assert_##MSG[(CONDITION)?1:-1]
```

This makes it possible to transfer an error message in the condition, which is handy to explain what's going wrong if it ever gets triggered.

However, this `MSG` is a lot different from the one in `C11`'s `static_assert()` :

- It must be a single word
- It must use only identifier characters
- It cannot be a string with double quotes

This is so different from `C11`'s `static_assert()` that it seems impossible to create a macro which would switch transparently between the `C11` and the `C90` version depending on the compiler.

In an effort to accept an error message which "looks like `C11`", aka a string with double quote, I've tested a new macro :

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(CONDITION, MSG) \
typedef char static_assert[((void)(MSG), ((CONDITION)?1:-1))]
```

Using the `,` comma operator, this macro should accept `MSG` as a string, and just disregard it. But it will be displayed in case of error, which is the intention.

It works fine on `clang`, [but not of `gcc`](https://godbolt.org/z/-e91t6) : `error: variably modified at file scope`.

I'm trying to understand why, and if there is a work around

Comment: Go with the linux [BUILD_BUG_ON](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/build_bug.h#L29). `#define static_assert(cond, msg) BUILD_BUG_ON(cond)`

Comment: @KamilCuk - that's a great link and idea, but there seems to be quite a bit of `#include` entanglements beyond simply  the `BUILD_BUG_ON` macro. Am I missing something simple? (for the `__OPTIMIZE__` case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the typedef-array-trick with the enum-trick, then you will get something that seems to work with both clang and gcc:

```
#define CONDITION 1

#define TOKENPASTE(a, b) a ## b // "##" is the "Token Pasting Operator"
#define TOKENPASTE2(a,b) TOKENPASTE(a, b) // expand then paste
#define static_assert(x, msg) enum { TOKENPASTE2(ASSERT_line_,__LINE__) \
    = 1 / (msg && (x)) }

static_assert( CONDITION, "This should pass");
static_assert(!CONDITION, "This should fail");
```

This gives me, with gcc for example, on line 9 of foo.c:

```
foo.c:9: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
 static_assert(!CONDITION, "This should fail");
 ^
foo.c:9: error: enumerator value for 'ASSERT_line_9' is not an integer constant
 static_assert(!CONDITION, "This should fail");
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(Here the gcc switch `-ftrack-macro-expansion=0` is used, as the extra error messages are not that helpful and just add noise.)

Note that some mangling of the name is still necessary, which you omitted. Here the text `ASSERT_line_` is combined with the variable `__LINE__`. This ensures a unique name, provided:

- You don't use it twice on a single line.
- You don't use it in header files (or trust to luck).
- Your code doesn't happen to use the identifiers like `ASSERT_line_9` elsewhere.

For header files, you will need to add somewhere a single word with only identifier characters. For example:

```
#define static_assert3(x, msg, file) enum { TOKENPASTE2(file,__LINE__) = \
    1 / (msg && (x)) }
#define static_assert(x, msg) static_assert3(x, msg, my_header_h_)
```

If this fails on line 17, gcc will give an error such as:

```
 error: enumerator value for 'my_header_h_17' is not an integer constant
```

An alternative for the mangling in header files is to replace `__LINE__` with `__COUNTER__`. I've not used it, because it is non-standard and because clang was slow to adopt it. But now it has been in gcc, msvc, and clang for about five years.

---

You could try the same modification with your typedef-array idea, and replace the comma operator with `&&`. Then your gcc error changes into a warning. For example, modifying your godbolt example to:

```
typedef char static_assert_2["hello world!" && (CONDITION) ? 1 : -1];
```

gives the unwanted `warning: variably modified 'static_assert_2' at file scope` for gcc.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(CONDITION, MSG) { typedef char test[(CONDITION)?1:-1]; (void)(test*) #MSG; } (void)0
```